# Flutter BloC couldn't find correct provider when context.read is called

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc, flutter-cubit

I created a basic project to learn Flutter better. In `bnb.dart` file if I use:

```dart
context.read<AppBottomNavigationBarState>().selectedIndex
```

to change the `currentIndex` field of the `BottomNavigationBar`. The application throws:

```
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building
BlocBuilder<AppBottomNavigationBarCubit,
AppBottomNavigationBarState>
```

But if I change that line to:

```dart
state.selectedIndex
```

it works correctly. Why does it work when I change the line?

Down below you can see the dart files for my project.

`bnb_cubit.dart`:

```dart
class AppBottomNavigationBarCubit extends Cubit<AppBottomNavigationBarState> {
  AppBottomNavigationBarCubit()
      : super(AppBottomNavigationBarState(selectedIndex: 0));

  void change(int index) =>
      emit(AppBottomNavigationBarState(selectedIndex: index));
}
```

`bnb_state.dart`:

```dart
class AppBottomNavigationBarState {
  int selectedIndex;
  AppBottomNavigationBarState({required this.selectedIndex});
}
```

`bnb.dart`:

```dart
class AppBottomNavigationBar extends StatelessWidget {
  AppBottomNavigationBar({super.key});

  final List<Widget> screens = [HomeScreen(), SearchScreen(), LibraryScreen()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<AppBottomNavigationBarCubit,
        AppBottomNavigationBarState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Scaffold(
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            items: const [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home_filled),
                label: "Home",
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                label: "Home",
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.library_books),
                label: "Home",
              ),
            ],
            onTap: (value) {
              context.read<AppBottomNavigationBarCubit>().change(value);
            },
            currentIndex:
                context.read<AppBottomNavigationBarState>().selectedIndex,
          ),
          body: screens[state.selectedIndex],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

`main.dart`:

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<AppBottomNavigationBarCubit>(
      create: (context) => AppBottomNavigationBarCubit(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: AppBottomNavigationBar(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to read `AppBottomNavigationBarCubit` to get the current state.

So it will be

```dart
currentIndex:
        context.read<AppBottomNavigationBarCubit>().state.selectedIndex,
```

Answer (score 1):

You should access it using `Cubit`

```js
context.read<AppBottomNavigationBarCubit>().state.selectedIndex
```

not `State`

```js
context.read<AppBottomNavigationBarState>()
```

Since you're only providing `AppBottomNavigationBarCubit` not `AppBottomNavigationBarState` :

```js
return BlocProvider<AppBottomNavigationBarCubit>()
```

you're getting error `couldn't find correct provider`